# How to get ng-repeat to work inside of a directives template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Issue: Compile syntax {{vm.names}} spits out the variable, so I know the view has access to it. However, using vm.names inside directives like ng-repeat has no effect. I did a console.log(typoeof()) which says "object" so I know its not a string.

Code:

```
 function nameDirective (){
    return {
      template: [
        '{{vm.names}}',
        '<tr ng-repeat"name in vm.names">',
          '<td>{{name.id}}</td>',
          '<td>{{name.fName}}</td>',
          '<td>{{name.lName}}</td>',
        '</tr>'
      ].join(''),
      "scope":{
        names:"="
      },
      "controller": nameDirectiveCtrl,
      "controllerAs": 'vm'
    };
  }

  function  nameDirectiveCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.names = $scope.names;
  }
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/6vlqXFshSxPe5b3Wu7mf?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that you are missing `=` in `ng-repeat"name in vm.names"`. But this is not the real issue though.

Another problem is that you need to add `restrict: 'E'` if you use `<name-directive names="vm.names"></name-directive>`. But this also will not render anything.

After that I realized that you also need `replace: true`. In this case `ngRepeat` will work but strange ... rows will appear outside the table!

http://plnkr.co/edit/y8Wr2j1mLc3UFvFKo7IB?p=preview

Hm.. So here is the solution.

This is the rare case when you should use directive restricted to a comment. The problem with your current approach is that `<name-directive>` element can't be a direct child of the `tbody`, so browser fixes invalid markup moving your element directive somewhere else outside.

Below is the fixed directive code with comment syntax:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- directive: name-directive vm.names -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And directive will look like:

```
function nameDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'M',
        template: [
            '<tr ng-repeat="name in vm.names">',
                '<td>{{name.ID}}</td>',
                '<td>{{name.fName}}</td>',
                '<td>{{name.lName}}</td>',
            '</tr>'
        ].join(''),
        scope: {
            names: "=nameDirective"
        },
        replace: true,
        controller: nameDirectiveCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qTII5HdZP1gXKKZjOXTu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this. Alternatively http://plnkr.co/edit/VDcM532vu55JUhXgAwP7?p=preview. Also EA is the default for AngularJS 1.3 +